# Get runtime type of class containing instance of my class

Tags: scala, reflection, types

```
object GetTypeNameOfClassContainingSomeInstance {
  implicit class GetsTypeNameOfContainingClass(x: Any) {
    def containingClassTypeName: String = ???
  }
}

class Foo {
  import GetTypeNameOfClassContainingSomeInstance._
  def foo(x: Any): Unit = {
    println(s"${x.containingClassTypeName} owns this ${x.getClass}: $x")
    // should print something like "Foo owns this <class of x>: x" 
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that `containingClassTypeName` knows well enough to return `"Foo"`?

Comment: I think this could be done in a macro where you have access to the AST. What you want to do slightly resembles the debug macro in [this tutorial](http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/12/starting-with-scala-macros-a-short-tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def containingClassTypeName: String = {
  val st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace
  st(2).getClassName
}
```

This is an awful hack, but so is whatever you're trying to do.